# Как сохранить текст в EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть строчка EditText , что нужно сделать что бы введённые в неё данные не стирались после выхода или закрытия Activity ?

Comment: воспользуйтесь SharedPreferences - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences например, тогда данные будут храниться в памяти устройства

Comment: А можно сделать так что бы они хранились прямо в EditText ? что бы в случаи чего их можно было стереть и написать что то другое ? Как в этом видео : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7NXFbIrYqI&list=LL&index=1]

Comment: ну так вы сохраняете данные в памяти, дальше проверяете если они есть то делаете setText или другим способом устанавливаете текст из памяти в поле, и дальше редактируете когда нужно